# sql group rows by multiple properties

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table which represents a chart object structured like this

```
idChart, bar_indicator , value, name , type_chart , pie_indicator
1;"january";14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
1;"february";14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
1;"march";14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
2;"";50000;"Quote Pending";"pie";"Correction";
2;"";50000;"Quote Pending";"pie";"Evolution";
```

The idChart column allow to differenciate a chart from another.
So in the datas above we have 2 set of chart

```
 1;"january";14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
 1;"february";14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
 1;"march";14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
```

and

```
2;"";50000;"Quote Pending";"pie";"Correction";
2;"";50000;"Quote Pending";"pie";"Evolution";
```

Is it possible with a sql query to group the chart in order to have only 2 rows?
Something like this at output

```
1;"january","february","march";14,14,14;"Quote Pending";"bar";"";
2;"";50000,50000;"Quote Pending";"pie";"Correction,Evolution";
```

Because if a do a simple select statement then i get 5 rows when i process the query with jdbc. One row for one chart and this is not good

Thank you very much

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel . PostgreSQL

Comment: Check this link for converting rows to single column, http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Converting%20row%20values%20in%20a%20table%20to%20a%20single%20concatenated%20string.aspx        you can use group by to group for idChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
select idChart, 
       string_agg(bar_indicator, ',') as indicators,
       string_agg(value::text, ',') as values,
       string_agg(name, ',') as names
  from charts
  group by idChart
  order by idChart
```

Comment: You can also define [your own](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xaggr.html) "aggregate functions" or some of other [built in](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html)